Enable Postgis extension for PostgreSQL 15
ERROR:  Could not open extension control file "/Library/PostgreSQL/15/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory.extension "postgis" is not available 

ERROR:  extension "postgis" is not available
SQL state: 0A000
Detail: Could not open extension control file "/Library/PostgreSQL/15/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory.
Hint: The extension must first be installed on the system where PostgreSQL is running.

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL and Postgis extension on a Mac.
I've tried to follow various online instructions and had no luck so far.
Below are my installation steps:
I've installed PostgreSQL 15 using
brew install postgresql@15

The path for the PostgreSQL is at: /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@15. I started postgresql@15 with
brew services start postgresql@15

Then I use brew install postgis to install the postgis extension. It's installed at /opt/homebrew/opt/postgis.

I've found Postgres.app to be much more conventient than installing PosgreSQL using brew.
